# Optimize CSS selectors for brevity

Tags: css

```
#page-447 .entry-title, #page-447 .entry-header,
#page-1236 .entry-title, #page-1236 .entry-header,
#page-995 .entry-title, #page-995 .entry-header,
#page-136 .entry-title, #page-136 .entry-header,
#page-1425 .entry-title, #page-1425 .entry-header {
    display: none;
}
```

Is there a way to improve on the above for brevity?  As more and more pages are added the selector list will grow longer.

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the responses thus far.  I should have provided more info:

Unfortunately this is generated code so I cannot add classes to individual pages except via JavaScript.  I want to start by seeing if perhaps there is a CSS selector solution before going that route.

Comment: Is there a logic which pages are need to be hidden?

Comment: Page IDs are arbitrary e.g. (\d+).

Comment: Since you're already using JS, why not add a class to the page based on detecting the page with JS, instead of using a complex CSS selector? (get JS to do the hard work)

Comment: I have considered using jQuery ID selectors e.g. $("#page-447") along with addClass("clazz").  But first want to see if there are other options using CSS.

Comment: @PatrickGarner so some of them must remain visible, while other hidden, correct? You don't want to simple hide all "#page-xxxx" elements?

Answer (score 0):

What about this one:

```
.entry-title, .entry-header {
    display: none;
}
```

You could add a class to the pages where the elements should be hidden:

```
.hidden .entry-title, .hidden .entry-header {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: what if entry title and entry head should not be hidden when they are in other kinds of container (although in this case looks like they are contained only by the so-called *page*)

Comment: I should have provided a little more info.  See my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add pages to your selector, add classes as flags to those elements.

Comment: I should have provided a little more info.  See my updated question.